# HTML5 video seek not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm using Version 40.0.2214.10 beta (64-bit) of Google Chrome. The following always logs **0** in the console (whereas it logs **1.4987** with safari). Tests are done locally with `php -S localhost:8888`. Video is hosted locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
video{
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<video>
  <source src="videos/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="videos/vid.webmhd" type="video/webm">
  <source src="videos/vid.oggtheora.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<script>
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    video.currentTime=1.4987;
    console.log(video.currentTime);
  })
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the video "canplay" when you press the key?

Comment: yes. First it's hosted locally, second, however long I wait before pressing the key, I get the same result.

Comment: hmmm, is the video playing just fine when you press the key? (i don't see a play() anywhere)

Comment: I don't want to play the video. But if I do add a `play()` after the `console.log` it just plays from 0.

Comment: you can't set time time if it's not playing. chrome doesn't always fetch the video ahead of time if it's not playing, so you might not have the segment ready to play when you jump to that position. i would preload the video and call play() before i jumped around.

Comment: if the video is playing (and fully loaded) and I press a key (ie I set currentTime), it restarts to 0. `console.log` also writes 0 then.

Comment: given all that, it sounds and looks like a bug. 64bit mac chrome is brand-spanking-new, so this problem might very well fix itself.

Comment: That was my thought as well. This latest update is quite buggy.